# Flutter/ get PDF file from URL

Tags: flutter

```
void getFileFromUrl(String uri) async {
    var fileName = 'testonline';
    try {
      var _uri = Uri.parse(uri);
      var data = await http.get(_uri);
      var bytes = data.bodyBytes;
      var dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      File file = File("${dir.path}/" + fileName + ".pdf");
      print(dir.path);
      File urlFile = await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);
      _pdfController = PdfController(document: PdfDocument.openFile(dir.path));
    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception("Error opening url file");
    }
  }
```

Hello I am developing website with Flutter,

I would like to present PDF file on my website.

```
getFileFromUrl(
    'https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf');
```

I am calling this function in inistate on my web site, this link is the testing pdf link which is valid link.

But I am getting this error.

```
Error: Exception: Error opening url file
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:58701/dart_sdk.js:5037:11)
    at membership_agreement_screen._MembershipAgreementScreenState.new.getFileFromUrl
    (http://localhost:58701/packages/clio_application_portal/screens/membership_agreement_screen.dart.lib.js:1312:23)
    at getFileFromUrl.throw (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:58701/dart_sdk.js:37379:38
    at _RootZone.runBinary (http://localhost:58701/dart_sdk.js:37249:59)
    at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleError (http://localhost:58701/dart_sdk.js:32511:48)
    at handleError (http://localhost:58701/dart_sdk.js:33044:51)
    at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:58701/dart_sdk.js:33070:17)
    at _Future.new.[_completeError] (http://localhost:58701/dart_sdk.js:32920:23)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:58701/dart_sdk.js:32956:31)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:58701/dart_sdk.js:37497:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:58701/dart_sdk.js:37503:13)
    at http://localhost:58701/dart_sdk.js:33274:9
```

Please let me know what is wrong...

I am waiting for you help..

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Can you update the question with the value of `e` from the catch block? 
Since the code above is printing a static string its unclear what exactly is the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume the problem is that this is a cross origin call, which is not allowed in a website. This has nothing to do with flutter though. But is a security feature enforced by the browsers.

If you want to serve some pdf file from another host than you are serving the JavaScript you have to either have control over the server hosting the PDF to add CORS headers, or add a reverse proxy on the same host of your JavaScript which proxies all requests.

Flutter describs this problem for images, but it just as well effects any http connections: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/web-images#cross-origin-images

Comment: errr.. reading the code again.. You said you were developing a website with flutter.. but you are using `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory` which won't work on the Web anyway. So I'm pretty confused now. ‍♂️️

Comment: Yeah the error is most likely caused by using the `dart:io` library in a browser environment.

Comment: @RohanThacker i'm pretty sure it's both. If you open the javascript console you should see the CORS error for the request.

Comment: Hmm,,, Ok I know the code is wrong, but I getting the error on var data = await http.get(_uri); this line. My question is, is it possible to get the pdf file form url in web ?

Comment: @DaegilPyo and I've answered exactly that question. Maybe read my answer. You can load from the same origin as the app is loaded. If you want to load from another host, this host has to add CORS headers. If you don't have control over the host of the PDF you have to provide a proxy server which you control and can add CORS headers to (or serve from the same host as your app)